# Google apps script drive file: How to get user who last modified file?

Tags: google-apps-script

To get the date a file was last updated you can call  [getLastUpdated()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getLastUpdated())

How to I get the **user** who did this last update in google apps script code?

I have tried to run the code under *listing revisions* at [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)

```
var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
```

but I get

```
ReferenceError: "Drive" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

In Resouces > Advanced Google services, turn on Drive API...

[image]

In that same window > click Google Developer's Console >> enable both Drive API and Drive SDK...
[image]

then...

```
Drive.Files.get('<FILEDID>').lastModifyingUser
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.. TypeError: Cannot call property lastModifyingUser in object

Comment: @dsme start a new post then with the code and steps you used

Comment: You might need to enable the services in the [Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear:

First enable the drive API and SDK as [described by Bryan P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28019679/3002139). Then you can use

```
var lastemailuser =  Drive.Files.get(<FILEDID>).lastModifyingUser.emailAddress;

var lastnameuser =  Drive.Files.get(<FILEDID>).lastModifyingUserName;
```