# Drive.Files.get(fileid).LastModifiyingUser.emailaddress can't find the file in the shared drive using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

For a script that documents all the spreadsheet files with references in formulas to another spreadsheet, I want to retrieve the last modifying user of a file.
This apps script is only being used within the domain I am owning; the spreadsheet documents exist both in MyDrive as in our shared drive.

I am using the following statement:

`var docModifierEmail = Drive.Files.get(docId).lastModifyingUser.emailAddress`

Documentation is very hard to find
The error I'm getting all the time is:

```
API call to drive.files.get failed with error: File not found: 1Nz0_Kme172EQXAwgW55d7H.....
```

The scope I am using:

```
>       "oauthScopes": [
>           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
>           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
>           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
>           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity"  <--- not sure if this is needed
```

Questions that I have:

1. Am I using the right function call?
2. Am I using the right scope?
3. What should be the right statement to retrieve the last modifying user's
   email address of the file with id `docId`?

Comment: Please see both answer and comments of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28019679/11225291) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606803/file-not-found-error-google-drive-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Drive API version 2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk?hl=en) available in Apps Script needs at least one of the following scopes for [Files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?hl=en):

**Scope:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly
```

---

When trying to access a file from your shared drive/team drive, You need to set the optional query parameter `supportsAllDrives` to **true**

```
Drive.Files.get("file id",{supportsAllDrives:true}).lastModifyingUser.emailAddress;
```

---

**Additional Reference:**

[File Resource Representation](http://The%20%5BDrive%20API%20version%202%5D%5B1%5D%20available%20in%20Apps%20Script%20needs%20at%20least%20one%20of%20the%20following%20scopes%20for%20%5BFiles.get()%5D%5B2%5D:%20%20**Scope:**%20%20%20%20%20%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive%20%20%20%20%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file%20%20%20%20%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly%20%20%20%20%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly%20%20%20%20%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata%20%20%20%20%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata%20%20%20%20%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly%20%20%20----------%20%20When%20trying%20to%20access%20a%20file%20from%20your%20shared%20drive/team%20drive,%20You%20need%20to%20set%20the%20optional%20query%20parameter%20%60supportsAllDrives%60%20to%20**true**%20%20%20%20%20%20Drive.Files.get(%22file%20id%22,%7BsupportsAllDrives:true%7D).lastModifyingUser.emailAddress;%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk?hl=en%20%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?hl=en%20%20%20%5B3%5D:%20https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en%20%20%20%5B4%5D:%20https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk?hl=en#what_can_you_do_with_google_drive_api)

Comment: Thank you Ron. 
I have added the scope to the already present list in APPSSCRIPT.JSON with no luck

Comment: Verify first if the file exist in your Google Drive. I also don't think this is a scope issue since normally it would be handled successfully in GAS

Comment: Thank you Ron. 
I have added the scope to the already present list in APPSSCRIPT.JSON with no luck.
And I have tested with a hard coded docId of a file that truly exists. No luck either.
Do you have a source where the LastModifyingUser is better documented? Or an example of working code.

Comment: Maybe it's good to mention that the file is on a Shared drive (previously called Teamdrive). Would that make a difference?

Comment: Thank you that was helpful, I was able to replicate your issue. Please see the updated answer

Comment: Great! That was the problem. Do you know where I should have found this documented?

Comment: It should be available in the [Drive.Files.gef()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?hl=en) optional query parameters.

Comment: Thank you Ron, I just upvoted your answer.