# rive.Files.get(fileID).lastModifyingUser.emailAddress is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a beginner in Google App Script. I want to fill a sheet with a google app script. For that I need to get the appropriate information. But I do not get the email address from the last modifying user. May you help what I can do to get the email address from the user who was the last one who modified the file? If I try the following code I get the error message:

*GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.get failed with error: File not found: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx*
listFilesInFolder   @ Code.gs:70

The xxx are just placeholder for the appropriate fileID. (This is working!)

Thank you very much in advance!

```
var fileID = file.getId();
lastmodifier = Drive.Files.get(fileID).lastModifyingUser.emailAddress;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't contain part how do you get the *file* object.

Only after reading your title I assume you used the *DriveApp*.

For the last *lastModifyingUser* you should use ***Drive***, not the *DriveApp*. Maybe that is the cause of your code break. You should use:

```
Drive.Files.get('<FILEDID>').lastModifyingUser
```

But first you have to enable Drive API in your project.

*DriveApp* is something like out of the box, for the most common tasks, *Drive* is more powerful, something like the next level, but you have to include it explicitly.

You have an answer to your question on this SO post
[Google apps script drive file: How to get user who last modified file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017673/google-apps-script-drive-file-how-to-get-user-who-last-modified-file)
together with the explanation how to enable Drive API.

Comment: So sorry. I posted the wrong code..

Comment: So sorry. I posted the wrong code..

The code is: 

```var fileID = file.getId();
lastmodifier = Drive.Files.get(fileID).lastModifyingUser.emailAddress;```

But I recieve the same message. You are right, I found that post but the configuration is different as there seems to be a new Apps Script envrionment. 

As I am working in a big company I guess I have to contact some one from IT to help me out with activating the API.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the `file` object already, it should already have the email of the last modifying user. You can reference it using:

```
file.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress
```

References:

[Google Drive API | Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

Comment: Sadly it does not finde the method "LastModifyingUser.emailAdress.